# Angularjs show directive based on controller variable

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I have a directive that only loads a template like this:

```
app.directive("sidebar", function(RESOURCE_URL) {
    return {
        templateUrl: RESOURCE_URL + 'sidebar.html'
    };
});
```

The HTML looks like this:

```
<sidebar ng-controller="sidebarCtrl" ng-show="ready"></sidebar>
```

And the controller:

```
app.controller('sidebarCtrl', function($scope, authService) {
    $scope.service = authService;
    $scope.ready = false;
    $scope.user = {};
    $scope.$watch('service.getUser()', function(value){
        $scope.user = value;
        $scope.ready = true;
    });
});
```

Is there a way to simply make the directive use the controller's scope variables? Or what's the common method to use in this case?

Comment: You can simply use a service variable to hold the common variable, inject it both in controller and directive..

Comment: Directives can have controllers too. Just add `controller: 'sidebarCtrl'` to your directive, and remove `ng-controller="sidebarCtrl"` from the HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 main ways to access some scope variables inside your directive, 
the first one is to enable scope inheritance inside of your directive by using scope: true

```
app.directive("sidebar", function(RESOURCE_URL) {
   return {
       scope: true,
       templateUrl: RESOURCE_URL + 'sidebar.html'
   };
});
```

which allows you to inherit outer scope inside of your directive, **the other way** is to attach the controller to your directive by using controller: sideBarCtrl:

```
app.directive("sidebar", function(RESOURCE_URL) {
  return {
      controller: 'sideBarCtrl',
      templateUrl: RESOURCE_URL + 'sidebar.html'
  };
});
```

**or,**  you can write a service to hold your scope variables and this will allow you access from different parts of your code to the same instance of the variable.

> https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/services